# Should I use str.something(…) or '…'.something()?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

My question is basically the title, in this case i use `.lower()` as the function,

So:

```
>>> s = 'A'
>>> s.lower()
'a'
>>> str.lower(s)
'a'
```

Which one is better, more preferred? (I think it should be the first one because it's easier, but still i don't know.)

Comment: I believe they are the same in your case, but sometimes you'll have to refer to the string functions without actually having the objects instantiated, and then `str.lower` is useful... for example, suppose you want to `lower` a pandas series (without using `StringMethods` from pandas module). You'd do `series.apply(str.lower)` because you don't actually have a string object here, but want to refer to `lower` anyway (now think of other applications in `reduce`, `map` etc)

Comment: @RafaelC That's right why didn't i think of that, because for map use `str.lower` because it's easier (no need lambda), so in different cases could be diffferent ones are the best

Comment: Well, that still implicitly creates a lambda

Comment: @cricket_007 what do you mean exactly? No new function is created when you use `str.lower`, if that's what you mean

Comment: @cricket_007 In CPython, an unbound method from a builtin type doesn't create _anything_, it just is the function exported from the builtin. (Even unbound methods from Python classes just are the function, since 3.0.) A different implementation might create an unbound method object, but it wouldn't be a new function. (I assume that's what you mean by "a lambda", because lambda is just a form of syntax for creating the same kind of functions as def, not a kind of object.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're just calling it directly, using the *bound method* `s.lower()` is definitely preferred. It says what you mean (object: do this!), it's shorter, it's more obvious to the reader, and it's even faster with builtin types like `str` (but about the same speed with types you create yourself).

---

The difference is when you need to store the method, or pass it around as a callback, etc., instead of calling it right away. In that case, it's almost always obvious what you want to do:

- If you're going to want to call the method on a string you haven't seen yet, or on a whole bunch of different strings, you want to store/pass/whatever the unbound method, `str.lower`.
- If you want to call the method on a string you have sitting around, especially if you want to call it over and over on that same string, you want to store/pass/whatever the bound method, `s.lower`.

---

For the case of `str.lower`, it's pretty easy to think of uses for the unbound method, like:

```
lower_strings = map(str.lower, strings)
```

Or, shamelessly stealing from [Dair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940765/908494), because it's a better example than mine:

```
sorted_strings = sorted(strings, key=str.lower)
```

But it's pretty hard to imagine why you'd ever want to call the bound method `s.lower` over and over again.

But consider these other cases with *different* methods:

- You're building a GUI, and you want a certain `onclick` method to get called on your window object every time a button is clicked. Obviously, you always want the method to get called on this particular window object, the one that owns the button, so you'll use the bound method `self.onclick` as your button callback, not the unbound method `Window.onclick`.
- You're looking for unique values, do you keep a set, `values_seen`, of all the values you've seen so far. `values_seen.add` might be a useful thing to store or pass to some other function, but `set.add` wouldn't do you any good.

---

There's also a third case you didn't mention:

```
lambda x: x.lower()
```

That's just like `str.lower`, in that you can pass it to `map` or save it for later, and more complicated, and slower. So, why would you ever do it?

Imagine you need a function that calls `lower` on anything that "duck types" as a string, not just actual strings. For example, `b'AbC'.lower()` is a perfectly valid thing to do. So, if you have a list of either strings or bytes but you're not sure which, and you want to lowercase them all, you can't `map(str.lower, xs)` or `map(bytes.lower, xs)`, but you can `map(lambda x: x.lower(), xs)`.

Although for that particular case you can—and usually should—just use a comprehension:

```
(x.lower() for x in xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

`.lower` is more general than `str.lower` since `str.lower` only works for strings. However, there are cases such as [`bytes.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.lower) where (between `str.lower` and `.lower`) `.lower` is the only way that works. Hence, unless you have some performance case, (or type checking case) I would advise toward more generality.

`str.lower` can still be convenient as it can be passed into functions like `map`, and as into the [key parameter for `sort`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) along with other related functions.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is easier if you want a one-time use, but generally, the first option is preferred.

If you plan to use the string at all in your following lines of code (which is probably true for 99% of code), you would almost definitely want a variable that you can refer to.

Comment: Ok, but `'..'.lower()` doesn't assign back too, no? or i miss something?

Comment: @U9-Forward Python strings are immutable, which therefore means no string methods ever assign back.

Comment: Why do you say the second one is easier for a one-time use?

Comment: @HSK What do you mean, no, you can `s=s.lower()`

Comment: @U9-Forward I thought you meant "assign back" as in that the method makes a change to the object itself, like list methods?

Comment: @HSK For me assign back is something like `a = a..`

Comment: @abarnert In the interest of simplicity, you sometimes might want to show the actual string directly. But if you only use a string once, you're probably doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: @MarkusZhang I don't know what you mean by "show the actual string directly". Either way, you're directly specifying either a string literal or a variable or another expression for the string.

Comment: @abarnert That is true. In almost all cases it is better to have a variable that references to a string. When I said "show the actual string directly", I meant it might be easier for someone reading the code to understand.